# How to push a docker image to Heroku, which is pulled from Docker Hub

Tags: heroku, rabbitmq, dockerfile

> after pushing it to heroku how to run the command "docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name some-rabbit rabbitmq:3-management"

Comment: Heroku is a _web_ host, and it expects to host web applications (i.e. ones that have a web server to listen for HTTP requests). Are you trying to run a web application, or an arbitrary service?

Answer (score 0):

Heroku may have provided you the private docker repository URL, change docker image name to `REPO_URL/rabbitmq:3-management`